# Нахождение значения в фрейме(или столбце) и при его нахождении добавить дополнительные строки

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Есть DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd
lst = {'Name':['car1', 'car2', 'car3', 'car4'], 'Type':[20, 21, 19, 18], 'Repair':["n", "n", "y", "n"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
print(df)
```

Нужно при нахождении значения `y` в нужном столбце добавить еще некоторое кол-во строк (i) с суффиксом `_Bit {i}`, но другие столбцы не изменять как в примере. Где  `i` меняется в диапазоне от 0 до 16.

```py
import pandas as pd
lst = {'Name':['car1', 'car2', 'car3','car3','car3','car3', 'car4'], 'Type':[20, 21, 19,19,19,19, 18], 'Repair':["n", "n", "y","y_bit0","y_bit1","y_bit2", "n"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
print(df)
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Пример:

Исходный DF:

```
In [85]: df
Out[85]:
   Name  Type Repair
0  car1    20      y
1  car2    21      n
2  car3    19      y
3  car4    18      n
```

создаем вспомогательный DF:

```
N =  3

t = pd.concat([df.query("Repair == 'y'")] * N, ignore_index=True).sort_values("Name")
```

---

```
In [87]: t
Out[87]:
   Name  Type Repair
0  car1    20      y
2  car1    20      y
4  car1    20      y
1  car3    19      y
3  car3    19      y
5  car3    19      y
```

изменяем значения в столбце `"Repair"`:

```
In [88]: t["Repair"] += "_bit" + t.groupby("Name")["Repair"].cumcount().astype(str)

In [89]: t
Out[89]:
   Name  Type  Repair
0  car1    20  y_bit0
2  car1    20  y_bit1
4  car1    20  y_bit2
1  car3    19  y_bit0
3  car3    19  y_bit1
5  car3    19  y_bit2
```

объединем исходный DF с вспомогательным:

```
In [90]: res = pd.concat([df, t], ignore_index=True).sort_values(["Name", "Repair"])

In [91]: res
Out[91]:
   Name  Type  Repair
0  car1    20       y
4  car1    20  y_bit0
5  car1    20  y_bit1
6  car1    20  y_bit2
1  car2    21       n
2  car3    19       y
7  car3    19  y_bit0
8  car3    19  y_bit1
9  car3    19  y_bit2
3  car4    18       n
```